# How to create an associative array from a delimited list?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm processing data from a readout from a storage device in this format:

```
id:name:UPS_serial_number:WWNN:status:IO_group_id:IO_group_name:config_node:UPS_unique_id:hardware:iscsi_name:iscsi_alias:panel_name:enclosure_id:canister_id:enclosure_serial_number:site_id:site_name
10:node_A::00A550:online:0:io_grp0:yes::SV1:iqn.1986-03.com:2145.test.nodeA::A:::::
15:node_B::00A548:online:0:io_grp0:no::SV1:iqn.1986-03.com.:2145.test.nodeB::B:::::
```

How can I read that data as a 2D array, like `datarray['15']['status']`?

I tried this way:

```
# Create array
datarray = []
try:
    # Loop trough list
    for i, x in enumerate(lis):
        # Split on the delimter
        linesplit = x.split(":")
        row = []
        for lsi,lsx in enumerate(linesplit):
            row.append([lsi,lsx])
        datarray.append(row)
```

But that seems to slice the the data wrong:

```
[[[0, u'id'], [1, u'name'], [2, u'UPS_serial_number'], [3, u'WWNN'], [4, u'status'], [5, u'IO_group_id'], [6, u'IO_group_name'], [7, u'config_node'], [8, u'UPS_unique_id'], [9, u'hardware'], [10, u'iscsi_name'], [11, u'iscsi_alias'], [12, u'panel_name'], [13, u'enclosure_id'],
```

Comment: What you are calling "associative array" is a `dict` in python. `dict` and `list` are completely different types of data. You should read some documentation on python basic data types to understand how to achieve what you want.

Comment: This seems to be a CSV file with colons as separators? If so, you can just use `csv.DictReader` from the standard library to turn the file into an iterator of dictionaries. And then you can turn that into a list of dictionaries just by calling `list(reader)`, and you’re done.

Comment: BTW, there seems to be one more `:` in the data rows than in the header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to read the individual lines as dictionaries and then use a dictionary comprehention to create the "outer" dict mapping the `ID` attribute to the inner dicts with that ID.

```
raw = """id:name:UPS_serial_number:WWNN:status:IO_group_id:IO_group_name:config_node:UPS_unique_id:hardware:iscsi_name:iscsi_alias:panel_name:enclosure_id:canister_id:enclosure_serial_number:site_id:site_name
10:node_A::00A550:online:0:io_grp0:yes::SV1:iqn.1986-03.com:2145.test.nodeA::A:::::
15:node_B::00A548:online:0:io_grp0:no::SV1:iqn.1986-03.com.:2145.test.nodeB::B:::::"""

reader = csv.DictReader(raw.splitlines(), delimiter=":")
result = {line["id"]: line for line in reader}
print(result["15"]["status"])  # 'online'
```

Note that this is not a 2D array but a dictionary of dictionaries (with dictionaries being associative arrays). As a simple 2D array, a query like `result["15"]["status"]` would not work.

Answer (score 1):

What I can make out of the data is that it is colon(:) separated data and first line has header. If that is the case you can load it to pandas dataframe as you load a csv file with separator = ':'. And then convert that dataframe to numpy array.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir('/Users/Downloads/')
df = pd.read_csv('train.txt',sep=':')
df

id  name    UPS_serial_number   WWNN    status  IO_group_id IO_group_name   config_node UPS_unique_id   hardware    iscsi_name  iscsi_alias panel_name  enclosure_id    canister_id enclosure_serial_number site_id site_name
10  node_A  NaN 00A550  online  0   io_grp0 yes NaN SV1 iqn.1986-03.com 2145.test.nodeA NaN A   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
15  node_B  NaN 00A548  online  0   io_grp0 no  NaN SV1 iqn.1986-03.com.    2145.test.nodeB NaN B   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

df.as_matrix()

array([['node_A', nan, '00A550', 'online', 0, 'io_grp0', 'yes', nan,
        'SV1', 'iqn.1986-03.com', '2145.test.nodeA', nan, 'A', nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan],
       ['node_B', nan, '00A548', 'online', 0, 'io_grp0', 'no', nan,
        'SV1', 'iqn.1986-03.com.', '2145.test.nodeB', nan, 'B', nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Would be useful if you can post the code as well as output. So anyone coming again on the link can make use of your answer. Thanks

Comment: IMO suggesting the use of `pandas` to solve this is complete overkill, especially since the OP seems new to Python.